# Millisecond time in a shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script, date

How can someone print the entire time ie, for example 12:07:59:393(HH:MM:SS:milliseconds) in milliseconds. I found a lot of posts saying how to print Milliseconds along witht HHMMSS but I want to print the realtime clock in milliseconds. I'm using Linux.

Comment: Are you interested in the entire wall clock run-time for programs started by the shell or are you interested in the time-of day-value with millisecond granularity?

Comment: I am printing log packets and I need the timestamp to be in milliseconds when i print each line (wallclock precision) not time-of-day-value with millisecond granularity

Comment: If you are looking for a portable method, then the answer is: no, there is no way to do that. If you are on linux only, you may use `date`.

Answer (score 7):

This will give you how many miliseconds have passed since the beginning of the Unix epoch :

```
date +%s%3N
```

You have to reduce the seconds*1000 which have passed until 00:00 AM today. 
Or you can just convert everything into miliseconds from this formula :

```
date +%H%M%S%3N
```

Like :

```
h=$(date +%H)
m=$(date +%M)
s=$(date +%S)
ms=$(date +%3N)
echo $((10#$h*3600000 + 10#$m*60000 + 10#$s*1000 + 10#$ms))
```

Executing this took me 4 miliseconds in average, you might want ot reduce that time.

Edit : If there is a leading zero in one of the variables the script will fail. I added 10# in front of the variable names, to strip the leading zeros, so that we get, for example, 8 instead of 08.

Comment: `date +%s` is non-portable and there is no portable way to retrieve more than second granularity from `date`.

Comment: the question is tagged /linux.  your anti-GNU prejudice is not applicable here.

Answer (score 3):

See if perl is portable enough:

```
perl -MTime::HiRes=time -MPOSIX=strftime -e '
    $now = int(time() * 1000);
    printf "%s.%03d\n", strftime("%H:%M:%S", localtime(int($now/1000))), ($now % 1000);
'
```

[Time::HiRes](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/HiRes.html) and [POSIX](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html) are both core Perl modules.

If you just want the epoch timestamp with fractional seconds:

```
$ perl -MTime::HiRes=time -le 'print time()'
1462218218.49011
```